# Changing UserDefaultLanguage Swift problems

Tags: objective-c, swift3, nsuserdefaults, core-location, cllocationmanager

I am new to programming and I have found how to change the `CLLocation` reverse Geolocation only in Objective C:

```
 NSMutableArray *userDefaultLanguages = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"en", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];

[self.geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation:newLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
   MKPlacemark *placemarker = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
   NSLog(@"%@",placemarker.locality);
   }];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:userDefaultLanguages forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
```

And I have big difficulties to translate it in Swift, this is what I managed to do:

```
        let userDefLang = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "AppleLanguages")
var placeMark: CLPlacemark!
        placeMark = placemarks?[0]
        if let city = placeMark.addressDictionary!["State"] as? String
        {
            self.city = city as String
        } else
        {
            self.city = "CONNECTION"
        }
        if let country = placeMark.addressDictionary!["Country"] as? String
        {
            self.country = country as String
        } else
        {
            self.country = "FAILED"
        }
        self.currentCity.name = ("\(self.city), \(self.country)" as String)
```

but I dunno how properly to set the language and than change it back, please help me... The things I can not make are:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"en", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
```

and

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:userDefaultLanguages forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
```

**UPDATE**

I have made the changes like you told (I wish I understood how) this is the code:

```
   func convertLocationToCity()
{
    if let defaultLanguage = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "AppleLanguages") as? [String]
    {
        let newLang = ["en"]
        UserDefaults.standard.set(newLang, forKey: "AppleLanguages")

        let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
        let userLocation = CLLocation(latitude: self.lat, longitude: self.long)
        geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(userLocation, completionHandler:
            {

                (placemarks, error) -> Void in

                var placeMark: CLPlacemark!
                placeMark = placemarks?[0]
                var cityRef = ""
                var countryRef = ""
                if let city = placeMark.addressDictionary!["State"] as? String
                {
                    cityRef = city as String
                } else
                {
                    cityRef = ""
                }
                if let country = placeMark.addressDictionary!["Country"] as? String
                {
                    countryRef = country as String
                } else
                {
                    countryRef = ""
                }
                self.currentCity = ("\(cityRef), \(countryRef)" as String)
                if (self.didLoadCity == "" || self.didLoadCity == self.currentCity)
                {
                    self.didLoadCity = ("\(cityRef), \(countryRef)" as String)
                }
                print("\(self.currentCity)")
                self.cityNameLabel.text = self.currentCity
        })


        //After that set again defaultLanguage.
        UserDefaults.standard.set(defaultLanguage, forKey: "AppleLanguages")
    }

}
```

but still no changes, it shows me the response in phone's default language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you can use `array(forKey:)` and `set(_:forKey:)` on `UserDefaults` object like this.

```
if let defaultLanguage = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "AppleLanguages") as? [String] {
        let newLang = ["en"]
        UserDefaults.standard.set(newLang, forKey: "AppleLanguages")

        //Perform your Task here

        //After that set again defaultLanguage.
        UserDefaults.standard.set(defaultLanguage, forKey: "AppleLanguages") 
    }
```

Comment: thank you for answer, but something does not work, I updated my question.

Comment: `geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(` is work with closure, so it will work in async manner, so `UserDefaults.standard.set(defaultLanguage, forKey: "AppleLanguages")` put this line inside that closure at last after you complete your task. Means after this line `self.cityNameLabel.text = self.currentCity`.